# Cassandra performance updating rows over time

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to determine how suitable Cassandra is for my application, as it is unknown how much we will need to scale in the future and could occur rapidly.  I have been watching various segments of the C* Summit 2013.

Specifically, Axel Liljencrantz, Backend Developer at Spotify, [says here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=0u-EKJBPrj8#t=578) that you can expect Cassandra performance to degrade over time if your model requires you to update the same row over and over.

My model requirement is a "document store" kind of type with known fields, with values that change over a number of months, as it meets various real-life requirements/status points.  Various queries and counts need to be performed across different kinds of documents stored.

So: Are there any suitable ways to mitigate this, if all documents have typically the same known average life-time before they remained fixed, historical data?

Is it ill-conceived to work around this by storing a version number and rewriting the whole document to a new row as information is updated?

Comment: you can mitigate this by a full/major compaction. But this is something I only recommend if the dataset is quite small (<10GB), and you understand what a major compactions means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*that you can expect Cassandra performance to degrade over time if your model requires you to update the same row over and over*

--> It's due to the fact that the same row spans over dozen of SSTables (SizeTiered Compaction). There is the new Leveled Compaction available in Cassandra that can mitigate it, more info **[here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/leveled-compaction-in-apache-cassandra)**

*My model requirement is a "document store" kind of type with known fields, with values that change over a number of months, as it meets various real-life requirements/status points.*

If your document has "known fields", so there will be a fixed amount of "columns" per table. Although the update is frequent it's not a problem (provided that you choose Leveled Compaction as mentioned above) since is is not a "widerow"

*if all documents have typically the same known average life-time before they remained fixed*

If your documents change very frequently a couple of months before their final and immutable version, you can store them first in a column family **configured** to support frequent updates. After they become final, move them to another column family configured to be stable and read-efficient

Comment: Thanks, this has helped clarify things some.  How would I go about about querying the data as a single set, in this scenario?  So the documents can be searched.  I am under the understanding that queries are limited to a single column family.

Comment: "How would I go about about querying the data as a single set, in this scenario?" --> Designing in Cassandra is crucial if you want to query your data. Type "Cassandra data model" on Google to find out how to design. And yes, with Cassandra we're no longer in the "SQL" world, queries are limited to the way you design your data. Forget about all the fuzzy text search.

Comment: agreed a second table is a good solution when the process is done