# cassandra not good for updates?

Tags: cassandra

I have 2 questions:

First: I heard cassandra is not good with the SQL statement UPDATE. It should not often happend. Is That truth? If yes WHY ?

Second: A user can create a post where users can like comment etc.
Now I want to order by most liked posts. How I do it in cassandra and how I store it ? I heard updates are not good every time so how can I denormalize it now ?

```
Table posts
CREATE TABLE posts_by_id (
 user_id UUID,
 post_id UUID,
 post_text TEXT,
 comments map<text>
 likes map<text>
 createdAt timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY ((post_id, user_id) NOW HOW CAN I SORT BY HIGHEST LIKES ?)
)
```

Comment: Can you share the source which says Cassandra is not good for updates? Also since (post_id,user_id) is a partition key so you cannot sort your post by number of likes. If user_id was the only partition key, then you can sort your posts for the user with most likes. Also likes should be number I think.

Comment: A good but old answer to similar question about updates in Cassandra: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811839/840340

Comment: @localdata01,  your post has multiple questions which are unrelated. I recommend posting your second question separately. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That statement isn't correct. Updates are a normal operation in Cassandra, just like any other databases.

If you provide your source, I will be happy to review it and update my answer. Cheers!