# cassandra should I use update or insert for updating?

Tags: cassandra

I heard I should avoid a lot of updating statements and delete statements. Can I use insert instead of update if I want to update a row ?

Comment: A similar question was asked previously and has a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811839/840340

Answer (score 1):

`Update` operation is  basically insert in Cassandra. In fact every write operation (Insert, Update and Delete) is insert only. As Cassandra is append only database, so new entry is inserted into database.

You need to understand why it is recommended to avoid too many updates and deletes in Cassandra. Basic reason is that your reads become slow with too many updates or deletes.

Cassandra writes(insert,update,delete) its data in immutable SSTables. With many updates(or inserts) and deletes your partition is present in multiple SSTables until compaction takes place. So to give you complete data Cassandra has to read all SSTables and then return the merge data.

Comment: Hey thanks but what are too many updates ? How much updates are too much?

Comment: That depends on lot of things (one is your compaction strategy LCS is suited for updates) . It also depends how frequently you are updating.  Multiple updates on same partition done in short period of time may end up in single sstable then you do not find any issue. It is a recommendation from community and if you find a number then I am sorry I do not have any number.

Comment: my problem is a user can like a posts. So if i have a table named posts and I set a liker as counter every time if a user liked the table get updated. So this increase the performance ..do you have another solution about this